# How to get term for current custom post without taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get term for current custom post dynamically on single page (for breadcrumbs for example)
I used get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'curr_post_tax' )
Or how to get curr_post_tax of current custom post
Or maybe you know others methods

Home>Catalog>Term>CurrProd

Answer (score 0):

The [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function returns an **array** of terms of the specified taxonomy. If you want just the first term from that array then:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'YOUR-TAXONOMY' );
                        
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
  echo $terms[0];
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask how to get the term for a Post **without** knowing the taxonomy in advance, we **cannot** use these functions because a `$taxonomy` or `$taxonomies` parameter is **required**:

- [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)
- [wp_get_object_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/)

Finding a term for a Post without reference to the taxonomy means you could be finding any kind of term: `tag`, `category`, `custom_taxonomy_1`, `custom_taxonomy_2`, etc. If a Post has a `tag` term and a `category` term, how will your breadcrumb know which term to use without knowing the taxonomy?

If you can guarantee that a Post has only **one** term, and that term is always a valid navigation breadcrumb, then searching without the taxonomy would be safe, and you could try the function below.

### Function: get_term_without_taxonomy

```
/**
 * Find a term for a Post using the term with the
 * lowest term_id (this can be changed by updating
 * the SQL statement).
 *
 * @param int     $post_id The WP_Post database ID.
 *
 * @return object $term    An object with properties from WP_Term.
 */
function get_term_without_taxonomy( int $post_id ): object|null {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    $sql = "";
    $sql .= "SELECT T.*, TT.taxonomy";
    $sql .= " FROM {$table_prefix}terms T";
    $sql .= " JOIN {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy TT ON ( TT.term_id = T.term_id )";
    $sql .= " JOIN {$table_prefix}term_relationships TR ON ( TR.term_taxonomy_id = TT.term_taxonomy_id )";
    $sql .= " JOIN {$table_prefix}posts P ON ( P.ID = TR.object_id )";
    $sql .= " WHERE P.ID = %d";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY T.term_id ASC";
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
    $sql .= ";";

    $query = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post_id );

    $term = $wpdb->get_row( $query, OBJECT );

    return $term;
}

/**
 * Pseudo-code example.
 */
$post_id = 1;
$term = get_term_without_taxonomy( $post_id );
// To get the taxonomy: $term->taxonomy
if ( is_object( $term ) ) {
    $breadcrumb = $level_1->name . ' > ' . $level_2->name . ' > ' . $term->name;
} else {
    // Oops. This Post has no term!
    $breadcrumb = $level_1->name . ' > ' . $level_2->name;
}
```